# HardHat recommends WSL2 for windows, but why?

Tags: hardhat, windows

Our work machine is a windows VM and no WSL options available, so I wanted to understand why Hardhat recommends WSL2? so that we can better understand the tradeoff we may be making when doing our developments.

Comment: i've used Hardhat on both. using WSL was better for package management, of node.js versions in particular which isn't really good on windows. So, yeah, package management in general is going to work better on wsl and probably package compatibility in general will likely be better for linux than windows